# AC through a resistor

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

So I have two questions that are related to each other. In an AC circuit, a resistor is connected to an AC source. My book says that the applied voltage has to overcome the potential drop in the resistance only. What does the word “overcome” mean here? Similarly in AC through an inductor, the book says there is not potential drop so the applied voltage has to overcome the back emf only. Why isn’t there any potential  drop in this case? And why does it have to OVERCOME the back emf?

Comment: Sounds like bad wording in the book. I wouldn’t focus on the word overcome.